# Check if Push is enabled for an iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have a function which should check if PushServices are enabled or not:

```
- (BOOL)isPushEnabled { 
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; 
    return application.enabledRemoteNotificationTypes != UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone; 
}
```

But even if i disable all sliders in my Notification Options in Settings, the method is returning true! i am on iOS 7!

Comment: As I remember, once you install it gives you an alert related to Push Notification, probably you prompted it YES. Try deleting APP and re-install.

Comment: Thats not a Solution...what if a User gives permission but later on the user denies it?! I think my App should be able to recognize it...

Comment: Have you selected `None` ? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28883/how-can-i-turn-off-push-notifications-for-individual-apps-in-ios-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/enabledRemoteNotificationTypes)

> The values in the returned bit mask indicate the types of notifications currently enabled for the app. These types are first set when the app calls the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method to register itself with Apple Push Notification Service. Thereafter, the user may modify these accepted notification types in the Notifications preference of the Settings app. This method returns those initial or modified values. iOS does not display or play notification types specified in the notification payload that are not one of the enabled types. For example, the app might accept icon-badging as a form of notification, but might reject sounds and alert messages, even if they are specified in the notification payload.

Which means, sorry you can't do what you are trying to do. You are just checking if your app registered any push notifications.

Comment: So the User can´t disable Push, if Push is once set to Yes at the install?! So it does´t depend which Setting is set in Notifications, i am always be able to send push messages and react to them in my app?!

Comment: I think push server pushes the message regardless of the device settings but user chooses to view them or not.